# Using Apache and mod_rewrite to direct traffic based in query string value

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying, essentially, to load balance two servers using (for reasons outside the scope of this question) the first character of a query string parameter in order to decide which server to send traffic.

To explain what I have so far, if we take "user" as the parameter, and assume there are two servers. Server One for serving users who’s names begin with letter between A and M, and a second server for N to Z.

So for example a request for

https://www.example.com/service/?***user=paul***

would go to

https://***a-m.internal.***example.com/service/?user=paul

And request for

https://www.example.com/service/?***user=orla***

would go to

https://***n-z.internal.***example.com/service/?user=orla

So far I have something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{Query_String} ^[\?\&]user=[n-z].*
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://n-z. internal .example.com/service/$1 [P]

RewriteRule ^(.*) https://a-m.internal.example.com/service/$1 [P,L]
```

Firstly, I just Rewrite if it is n-z, and append the URL to the rule ($1). If it doesn’t match n-z, then I send it to a-m by default.

I am new to mod_rewrite, and I can’t seem to find a combination or permutation that will behave as I want.

Could someone explain why I don’t get the expect result?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*\&)?user=[a-m]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://a-m.internal.example.com/$1 [QSA,P]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*\&)?user=[n-z]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://n-z.internal.example.com/$1 [QSA,P]
```

Comment: Thanks. There is still a problem though - I need a default so requests without a "?user" will still get served (either server is fine for those requests, I can load balance them normally at a later stage).  Sticking a "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://n-z.internal.example.com/$1 [P]" without a preceeding Cond doesn't seem to work?

Comment: try removing only this line : `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*\&)?user=[n-z]`